# Why does the Java API mandate that setDefaultUseCaches be accessed non-statically?

Tags: java, api, conventions, urlconnection, calling-convention

After using the now essentially defunct Java Web Start (as the latest Java update has just essentially killed it), I found a situation which required me to call urlConn.setDefaultUseCaches(false).

However, I had to first construct I found that while the variable was clearly "sticky" and upon further inspection of the source code, I found that the variable is indeed a static boolean. So why is the variable accessed through a non-static method?

After all, even the getter method for the static boolean is non-static? Is this intentional?
I mean isn't it convention that static variables be accessed by static methods?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, and how does knowing why Java is designed that way help you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug.  Quote directly from the bug ticket: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4851466

> setDefaultUseCaches() should have been made static, but it can't be changed
>   now without impacting binary compatibility. The effect of it being non static
>   is just that you need to create an instance before invoking it, which is not
>   such a severe problem. In other words, there is not sufficient justification for
>   adding a new static method that does it exactly the right way. So we will not be able to fix this.